# Unable to execute mongo:find function in erlang

Tags: mongodb, erlang

Using mongodb erlang driver my program able to connect mongodb database server.
After successful connection I tried to all the documents present in the collection.

I tried the below code:

```
mongo:do (safe, master, Conn, graph, fun() ->
    process(mongo:find (pedgedata0, {src,1})) end),
```

here 'graph' is dbname and 'pedgedata0' is collection.

I tried with different options like

```
mongo:do (safe, master, Conn, 'graph', fun() ->
    process(mongo:find ('pedgedata0', {})) end),
```

*** here I tried with single quotes for db and collection name and also specified an empty condition.

However I am getting  below error:

```
Conn is : <0.104.0>
** exception exit: undef
     in function  bson_binary:put_cstring/1
        called as bson_binary:put_cstring(<<"graph.pedgedata0">>)
     in call from mongo_protocol:put_message/3
     in call from mongo_connection:encode_request/2
     in call from mongo_connection:handle_call/3
     in call from gen_server:handle_msg/5
     in call from proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3
```

I am running this program from erlide(Eclipse addon for erlang).

Please help me to resolve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Please use the newer version of driver: https://github.com/comtihon/mongodb-erlang
There are renewed interfaces for mongo operations.